CGAL: How to speed up finding a spherical curve's self-intersections on a sphere using arrangements? My naive O(N^2) solution is faster for N <=600
I am trying to write performant code which is being bottlenecked by this procedure:
The problem
Given an oriented closed curve on a unit sphere (this curve is discretized as a "polyline" with spherical segments.),

Identify each face, and iterate the vertices on each face.

Establish a dual directed graph, where the direction is based off the curve's orientation. Two faces are connected if they share an edge. (For the example below, I arbitrarily chose the "right"-normal. The resulting directed graph is shown below).


Finding the faces of the arrangement requires solving all the self-intersections of the curve. Once the intersections are found, the faces can be found from the topology of the oriented curve.
Implementations
I have coded this procedure both with and without CGAL. The implementation using CGAL is O((N+K) log (N)) where N is the number of segments of the closed curve and K is the number of intersections found. From my experiments N >> K in general. Most of the time is spent in
CGAL::insert (code snippets are provided below), doing a surface sweep. I use CGAL::Arr_halfedge_direction::ARR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT (update: still trying to find out how) to construct the dual directed graph of these faces.
I have also coded this procedure using a naive O(N^2) spherical segment intersection finding algorithm. Surprisingly, it is much faster due to a smaller constant in the time complexity. My experiments show that my implementation is faster until N is roughly 600. Most of my data has around 50 to 500 segments, which makes the CGAL code unusable. However, since I am new to the library I would like to ensure I am not missing out on massive performance improvements.
Performance considerations

I changed my kernel from using Exact Predicates and Exact Constructions to Exact Predicates and Inexact Constructions.
Almost all the time of my program (which does things beyond this procedure) is spent on the CGAL::insert used in creating the arrangement.


I understand that it does a surface sweep which is supposed to be O((N+K) log N), however  it's unclear to me how much processing CGAL does which is unrelated to my application, or related to solving arrangements on open curves.


I would like to eventually support multiple closed oriented curves on the sphere.

I don't think it's useful to try to parallelize this code since this procedure is already being called in parallel on different input curves.

CGAL Documentation has this page, giving tips on speeding up computation: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html#aos_sec-tips



1-6: I am unfamiliar with some of the terminology on this page but I believe that these don't apply.

7: I believe that I am doing #7 correctly (see code below).

8: I would rather use an exact type but I used inexact for performance reasons and it is still underwhelming.

9-10: I don't think they apply.


Please let me know if there is an oversight.
Code
typedefs
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel         Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2<Kernel>         Geom_traits;
typedef Geom_traits::Point_2                                      Point;
typedef Geom_traits::Curve_2                                      Curve;
typedef CGAL::Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2<Geom_traits>        Topol_traits;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<Geom_traits, Topol_traits> Arrangement;

Insertion
Geom_traits traits;
Arrangement arr(&traits);
auto ctr_p = traits.construct_point_2_object();
auto ctr_cv = traits.construct_curve_2_object();

for (int curve_index = 0; curve_index < spherical_curve.rows(); curve_index++)
{
    int first_index = curve_index;
    int second_index = (curve_index + 1) % spherical_curve.rows();

    Eigen::RowVector3d f_p = spherical_curve.row(first_index);
    Eigen::RowVector3d s_p = spherical_curve.row(second_index);
    arcs.push_back(ctr_cv(ctr_p(f_p(0), f_p(1), f_p(2)), ctr_p(s_p(0), s_p(1), s_p(2))));
}

CGAL::insert(arr, arcs.begin(), arcs.end());

For brevity, I am not including the code to create the directed graph and finding the vertices of each face. I did think these were important to mention as any optimization that does not allow me to do these is useless.
Edits
These edits are related to Efi Fogel's insightful response.
Exact data types
After running a few more experiments, I do see the need for exact data types as my custom implementation is not exact. There are numerous cases of erroneous intersections when I generate random points and it is completely true that the method should robustly find them all. However, the curves I'm using as input rarely have more than a handful intersections (0-5). In general, they are not degenerate and I've had success using my code on thousands of input curves without issues.
Fully working program
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <chrono>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_sweep_2_algorithms.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_on_surface_2.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using Kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using Geom_traits = CGAL::Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2<Kernel>;
using Point = Geom_traits::Point_2;
using X_monotone_curve = Geom_traits::X_monotone_curve_2;
using Curve = Geom_traits::Curve_2;

struct intersection {
    bool intersects;
    int end_point_intersection;
    Eigen::Vector3d location;
};


// Each spherical segment lies on a great circle. Great circles are planar and have a normal.
// This algorithm checks that segment1 i.e (p1, p2) has endpoints on separate sides of the plane of the plane from segment2's great circle.
// Then performs the same check with segment2's endpoints. There is an ambiguity if the two segments are the same or opposite sides of the sphere.
// The trigonomy at the bottom resolves this case. Most of the time spent in this code is normalizing vectors.
intersection spherical_segment_intersection(const Eigen::Vector3d& p1, const Eigen::Vector3d& p2, const Eigen::Vector3d& p3, const Eigen::Vector3d& p4)
{
    double epsilon = 0.000000005;

    struct intersection result;
    result.intersects = false;
    result.end_point_intersection = -1;

    Eigen::Vector3d great_circle_1_normal = p1.cross(p2).normalized();
    Eigen::Vector3d great_circle_2_normal = p3.cross(p4).normalized();

    Eigen::Vector3d p3_proj_dir = -great_circle_1_normal.dot(p3) * great_circle_1_normal;
    Eigen::Vector3d p4_proj_dir = -great_circle_1_normal.dot(p4) * great_circle_1_normal;

    if (p3_proj_dir.dot(p4_proj_dir) > 0)
        return result;

    Eigen::Vector3d p1_proj_dir = -great_circle_2_normal.dot(p1) * great_circle_2_normal;
    Eigen::Vector3d p2_proj_dir = -great_circle_2_normal.dot(p2) * great_circle_2_normal;

    if (p1_proj_dir.dot(p2_proj_dir) > 0)
        return result;

    double g1_norm = great_circle_1_normal.norm();
    double g2_norm = great_circle_2_normal.norm();

    great_circle_1_normal /= g1_norm;
    great_circle_2_normal /= g2_norm;

    if (1.0 - great_circle_1_normal.dot(great_circle_2_normal) < epsilon)
        return result;


    p3_proj_dir /= g1_norm;
    p4_proj_dir /= g1_norm;

    p1_proj_dir /= g2_norm;
    p2_proj_dir /= g2_norm;

    if (p1_proj_dir.norm() < epsilon)
    {
        result.end_point_intersection = 0;
        return result; // at endpoint 0
    }

    if (p2_proj_dir.norm() < epsilon)
    {
        result.end_point_intersection = 1;
        return result; // at endpoint 1
    }

    if (p3_proj_dir.norm() < epsilon)
    {
        result.end_point_intersection = 2;
        return result; // at endpoint 2
    }

    if (p4_proj_dir.norm() < epsilon)
    {
        result.end_point_intersection = 3;
        return result; // at endpoint 3
    }

    double t = -p1.dot(great_circle_2_normal) / great_circle_2_normal.dot((p2 - p1));
    Eigen::Vector3d intersection = p1 + (p2 - p1) * t;
    intersection.normalize();
    Eigen::Vector3d antipodal_intersection = -intersection;

    double theta_1_1 = std::acos(p1.dot(intersection));
    double theta_2_1 = std::acos(p2.dot(intersection));
    double theta_3_1 = std::acos(p1.dot(antipodal_intersection));
    double theta_4_1 = std::acos(p2.dot(antipodal_intersection));

    Eigen::Vector3d plane_1_intersection;
    if (theta_1_1 + theta_2_1 < theta_3_1 + theta_4_1)
        plane_1_intersection = intersection;
    else
        plane_1_intersection = antipodal_intersection;

    double theta_1_2 = std::acos(p3.dot(intersection));
    double theta_2_2 = std::acos(p4.dot(intersection));
    double theta_3_2 = std::acos(p3.dot(antipodal_intersection));
    double theta_4_2 = std::acos(p4.dot(antipodal_intersection));

    Eigen::Vector3d plane_2_intersection;
    if (theta_1_2 + theta_2_2 < theta_3_2 + theta_4_2)
        plane_2_intersection = intersection;
    else
        plane_2_intersection = antipodal_intersection;


    if (plane_1_intersection.dot(plane_2_intersection) < 0)
        return result; // don't intersect

    result.location = plane_1_intersection;
    result.intersects = true;
    return result;
}
 
int main()
{
    Eigen::IOFormat OctaveFmt(Eigen::FullPrecision, 0, ", ", ";\n", "", "", "[", "]");
    Geom_traits traits;
    auto ctr_pnt = traits.construct_point_2_object();
    auto ctr_cv = traits.construct_curve_2_object();
    auto make_x_monotone = traits.make_x_monotone_2_object();

    // I show an example of a typical curve used in the method.
    // In general these curves have # intersections << number of segments. Typically 0 to 5 intersections for hundreds of segments.
    // Generating random points tends to create more intersections than segments. 
    Eigen::MatrixXd curve(60,3);
    curve << -0.962746937823763, 0.1741138079042976, -0.2068881717451065,
        -0.9602600833963838, 0.178977377213232, -0.2141673893977384,
        -0.9595444292144757, 0.1833686986933843, -0.21365956262934,
        -0.9602511343581622, 0.1870351558488714, -0.2072090959404319,
        -0.9619737546233719, 0.1897888975890224, -0.1964348995666408,
        -0.9643419037563928, 0.191498407694676, -0.1826829288956675,
        -0.9670619439267535, 0.1920741921129118, -0.1670290433810268,
        -0.9699247232572765, 0.1914523825310668, -0.1503064085043399,
        -0.9727965090585146, 0.1895785040661569, -0.1331425655438763,
        -0.9756036021596218, 0.1863922664463346, -0.1159979933540621,
        -0.9783163801192787, 0.1818131741942531, -0.099201966108143,
        -0.9809352986790326, 0.1757259662297977, -0.08298388155588431,
        -0.9834794429846239, 0.1679642319215322, -0.06749964460398021,
        -0.9859771037630215, 0.1582897864053857, -0.05285351809313404,
        -0.9884570935365268, 0.1463642229279911, -0.0391163454837925,
        -0.9909386395638717, 0.1317070343724134, -0.02634140687448269,
        -0.9927975844943393, 0.1134458768968062, -0.03850959928796913,
        -0.9941923953152525, 0.0956641587378833, -0.04929350697905061,
        -0.9951836282403536, 0.0784908788624633, -0.0587258717922845,
        -0.9958316211940392, 0.06204415784683086, -0.06685734594739116,
        -0.9961949970371318, 0.04643075754858283, -0.07375440754052363,
        -0.9963294567845851, 0.03174605044679971, -0.07949718123533032,
        -0.9962868581596188, 0.0180743680956316, -0.0841772741087487,
        -0.9961145552026897, 0.00548965479756047, -0.08789571436396382,
        -0.9958549610352138, -0.005943644514190172, -0.09076105812209311,
        -0.9955452877620947, -0.01616952616305253, -0.09288770875821245,
        -0.9952174138910287, -0.0251392540792197, -0.09439447543364604,
        -0.9948978293433155, -0.03281011531084385, -0.09540338307024621,
        -0.994607609916204, -0.03914413983704453, -0.09603873496248375,
        -0.9943623758417294, -0.04410681147632935, -0.09642642112918377,
        -0.9941721919764943, -0.04766579002627026, -0.09669345976757687,
        -0.9939109561153587, -0.05342331232967167, -0.09636887990207149,
        -0.9937386623759105, -0.05940258817822943, -0.09462982308481742,
        -0.9936021577949703, -0.06574818835085094, -0.09182552887819274,
        -0.9934430330378051, -0.07261211224672973, -0.08830867037678006,
        -0.9931995527841092, -0.0801556947173295, -0.08443762759473743,
        -0.9928068835015073, -0.08855195043276602, -0.08057942756422123,
        -0.9921954402568265, -0.09798837252538543, -0.07711346953281611,
        -0.9912870628400313, -0.1086701836895289, -0.07443621580163677,
        -0.98998857324207, -0.1208239813965166, -0.07296704988982794,
        -0.9881820463129288, -0.1347015999049383, -0.07315546683497066,
        -0.9857108292334122, -0.1505837875089833, -0.07548962889979129,
        -0.982359971892118, -0.1687828960693014, -0.08050602225036663,
        -0.9778293175323765, -0.189643086307009, -0.08879935579788509,
        -0.971697188566472, -0.213535396387474, -0.1010307290959472,
        -0.9633727462226226, -0.2408431865556556, -0.1179301120375969,
        -0.9597334148275156, -0.2495671733314797, -0.1289495965827379,
        -0.9593630055378619, -0.2490173295699597, -0.1327139524662209,
        -0.9620353054302633, -0.2397602439722822, -0.130395922160364,
        -0.9672145669743911, -0.2221384688813099, -0.1230872945336297,
        -0.9741043609106133, -0.1964432038476508, -0.1119408849214441,
        -0.9816963711755098, -0.1631167516834347, -0.09831154632636209,
        -0.9888597289614367, -0.1229702792504584, -0.08387339780513373,
        -0.9944934730198315, -0.07737687335644011, -0.07067921611432408,
        -0.9977266325085548, -0.02837665538411504, -0.06112554467937792,
        -0.998099204589478, 0.02136480526786847, -0.05780590708325177,
        -0.9956251204242672, 0.06875508761107313, -0.06327209106515291,
        -0.9906632381491075, 0.110569783473164, -0.07975381848301843,
        -0.9836067467162295, 0.1437462695018188, -0.1088796483215564,
        -0.9744992977814755, 0.1656174475198544, -0.1514000650608165;

    int num_curves = curve.rows();
    std::vector<Curve> subcurves;
    subcurves.reserve(num_curves);

    Eigen::MatrixXd extended_curve = curve;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < curve.rows(); i++)
    {
        auto p1 = curve.row(i);
        auto p2 = curve.row((i + 1) % num_curves);
        auto cv = ctr_cv(ctr_pnt(p1.x(), p1.y(), p1.z()), ctr_pnt(p2.x(), p2.y(), p2.z()));
        subcurves.push_back(cv);
    }

    // 1. O(N^2)  
    auto time_before = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::vector<int> curve_ids(subcurves.size());
    std::iota(curve_ids.begin(), curve_ids.end(), 0);

    int current_curve_length = num_curves;

    int next_index = current_curve_length;

    for (int i = 0; i < curve_ids.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 2; j < curve_ids.size(); j++)
        {
            int idx1 = i;
            int idx2 = (i + 1) % curve_ids.size();
            int idx3 = j;
            int idx4 = (j + 1) % curve_ids.size();

            // skip neighboring segments
            if ((idx3 - idx1) <= 1)
                continue;
            if (idx4 == 0 && idx1 == 0)
                continue;


            assert(idx1 != idx2 && idx1 != idx3 && idx1 != idx4);
            assert(idx2 != idx3 && idx2 != idx4);
            assert(idx3 != idx4);


            if (!(curve_ids[idx1] != curve_ids[idx2] && curve_ids[idx1] != curve_ids[idx3] && curve_ids[idx1] != curve_ids[idx4]))
                continue;
            if (!(curve_ids[idx2] != curve_ids[idx3] && curve_ids[idx2] != curve_ids[idx4]))
                continue;
            if (!(curve_ids[idx3] != curve_ids[idx4]))
                continue;

            intersection intersection = spherical_segment_intersection(extended_curve.row(curve_ids[idx1]), extended_curve.row(curve_ids[idx2]),
                extended_curve.row(curve_ids[idx3]), extended_curve.row(curve_ids[idx4]));

            if (intersection.intersects)
            {
                if (intersection.end_point_intersection != -1)
                {
                    assert(false, "unimplemented");
                }
                else
                {
                    // topology update
                    // used later to construct the arrangement
                    curve_ids.insert(curve_ids.begin() + idx3 + 1, next_index);
                    curve_ids.insert(curve_ids.begin() + idx1 + 1, next_index);


                    // could be optimized but the number of intersections is generally small.
                    extended_curve.conservativeResize(extended_curve.rows() + 1, extended_curve.cols());
                    extended_curve.row(extended_curve.rows() - 1) = intersection.location;
                    current_curve_length++;
                    next_index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    auto time_after = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_diff = time_after - time_before;
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time_diff);

    std::cout << "Method = compute_intersection_points(), "
        << "Time = " << duration.count() << "microsecs, "
        << "# intersections: " << extended_curve.rows() - num_curves << std::endl;

    // 2. CGAL
    std::vector<Point> pts;
    time_before = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    CGAL::compute_intersection_points(subcurves.begin(), subcurves.end(),
        std::back_inserter(pts), true, traits);
    time_after = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    time_diff = time_after - time_before;
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time_diff);

    std::cout << "Method = compute_intersection_points(), "
        << "Time = " << duration.count() << " microsecs";

}


This is the curve used for the test.

Method = custom Time = 343 microsecs, # intersections: 2
Method = compute_intersection_points(), Time = 7929 microsecs

Using inexact constructions results in about 1700 microsecs for CGAL.

I would go a different way with this. Suppose your closed curve is represented as vector r(s) for s in [s1,s2]. Then you can define a surface D(x.y) = |r(x) - r(y)|^2 representing the square of the distance between two points on the curve. You then need to find the minimas of that surface where D(x, y) = 0. There may be libraries out there that can do this, or you can try to do it yourself with gradient descent, though finding ALL intersections might be tricky.

@SimonGoater Thank you for the suggestion. However, it's unclear if this would actually be faster. As you mention, there is no guarantee of finding all roots (intersections). Therefore, rerunning the rootfinding with different initial conditions at short intervals will be required to get some confidence on having found all of them. Moreover, the curves are assumed to be continuous but there is no assumption on continuity higher than c0. It's possibly that at a point the derivative is undefined (sharp turns). The method needs to be as robust as possible to any (possibly disgusting) input.

What do you want to have happen if the curve is not merely self-intersecting but retraces itself over a finite length?

@DavisHerring In my application, I use the area of each face for a weighted sum. Therefore, a curve retacing itself creates a face with 0 area, which has no impact on the final computation. Hence, it should either 1) still consider the topology and create a face which can be traversed, despite that the face has no area. 2) Alternatively, the face emerged from the retracement can be discarded

(1) You need to compare oranges with oranges. The CGAL code that you use is sensitive to inexact construction. Had you run the code (using inexact constructions) once in debug mode, you would have gotten an assertion and the program would have aborted. When you compute intersections and would like to be certain that the intersection points lie ON the input curves, you must use an exact-construction kernel.
(2) You don't say how you implemented the brute-force alg. Does your code support overlapping curves? What number type do you use?
(3) When you post code, post complete programs that can be compiled. Below is a benchmark that somehow compares various methods. I say somehow, because the first method operates only on curves, while the remaining three operate on x-monotone curves. In CGAL a geodesic arc that crosses the identification curve is considered non-x-monotone. The functor Make_x_monotone_2 subdivides a curve into at most 2 x-monotone curves; see the manual for further details.
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <chrono>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_sweep_2_algorithms.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_on_surface_2.h>

namespace ch = std::chrono;

using Kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using Geom_traits = CGAL::Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2<Kernel>;
using Point = Geom_traits::Point_2;
using X_monotone_curve = Geom_traits::X_monotone_curve_2;
using Curve = Geom_traits::Curve_2;
using Topol_traits = CGAL::Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2<Geom_traits>;
using Arrangement = CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<Geom_traits, Topol_traits>;
using Make_x_monotone_result = std::variant<Point, X_monotone_curve>;
using Intersection_point = std::pair<Point, Geom_traits::Multiplicity>;
using Intersection_result = std::variant<Intersection_point, X_monotone_curve>;

int main() {
  Geom_traits traits;
  auto ctr_pnt = traits.construct_point_2_object();
  auto ctr_cv = traits.construct_curve_2_object();
  auto make_x_monotone = traits.make_x_monotone_2_object();

  double a = 1;
  std::size_t num_curves = 50;
  std::size_t num_points = num_curves * 2;
  std::vector<Kernel::Point_3> points;
  points.reserve(num_points);
  std::vector<X_monotone_curve> xcurves;
  xcurves.reserve(num_curves);
  std::vector<Curve> curves;
  curves.reserve(num_curves);
  CGAL::Random r(23);
  CGAL::Random_points_on_sphere_3<Kernel::Point_3> g(1., r);
  std::copy_n(g, num_points, std::back_inserter(points));
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_points; i += 2) {
    const auto& p1 = points[i];
    const auto& p2 = points[i+1];
    Kernel::Vector_3 v1(p1, CGAL::ORIGIN);
    Kernel::Vector_3 v2(p2, CGAL::ORIGIN);
    auto cv = ctr_cv(ctr_pnt(v1.direction()), ctr_pnt(v2.direction()));
    curves.push_back(cv);
    std::vector<Make_x_monotone_result> xcvs;
    xcvs.reserve(2);
    make_x_monotone(cv, std::back_inserter(xcvs));
    const auto* xc = std::get_if<X_monotone_curve>(&(xcvs.front()));
    if (xc) xcurves.push_back(*xc);
    if (xcvs.size() == 2) {
      const auto* xc = std::get_if<X_monotone_curve>(&(xcvs.back()));
      if (xc) xcurves.push_back(*xc);
    }
  }
  auto num_xcurves = xcurves.size();
  std::cout << "# curves: " << num_curves << std::endl;
  std::cout << "# x-monotone curves: " << num_xcurves << std::endl;

  // 1 using Surface_sweep_2
  std::vector<Point> pts;
  auto time_before = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  CGAL::compute_intersection_points(curves.begin(), curves.end(),
                                    std::back_inserter(pts), true, traits);
  auto time_after = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto time_diff = time_after - time_before;
  auto duration = ch::duration_cast<ch::milliseconds>(time_diff);
  std::cout << "Method = compute_intersection_points(), "
            << "Time = " << duration.count() << "ms, "
            << "# intersections: " << pts.size() << std::endl;

  // 2. Constructing an arrangement using agregate insertions
  Arrangement arr1(&traits);
  time_before = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  CGAL::insert(arr1, xcurves.begin(), xcurves.end());
  time_after = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  time_diff = time_after - time_before;
  duration = ch::duration_cast<ch::milliseconds>(time_diff);
  std::cout << "Method = Arrangement aggregation insert(), "
            << "Time = " << duration.count() << "ms, "
            << "Arr cells: " << arr1.number_of_vertices() << ","
            << arr1.number_of_edges() << ","
            << arr1.number_of_faces() << std::endl;

  // 3. Constructing an arrangement using incremental insertions
  Arrangement arr2(&traits);
  time_before = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (const auto& cv : xcurves) CGAL::insert(arr2, cv);
  time_after = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  time_diff = time_after - time_before;
  duration = ch::duration_cast<ch::milliseconds>(time_diff);
  std::cout << "Method = Arrangement incremental insert(), "
            << "Time = " << duration.count() << "ms, "
            << "Arr cells: " << arr2.number_of_vertices() << ","
            << arr2.number_of_edges() << ","
            << arr2.number_of_faces() << std::endl;

  // 4. Brute-force
  auto intersect = traits.intersect_2_object();
  std::vector<Intersection_result> intersections;
  time_before = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (auto i = 0; i < num_xcurves-1; ++i) {
    for (auto j = i+1; j < num_xcurves; ++j) {
      intersect(xcurves[i], xcurves[j], std::back_inserter(intersections));
    }
  }
  time_after = ch::high_resolution_clock::now();
  time_diff = time_after - time_before;
  duration = ch::duration_cast<ch::milliseconds>(time_diff);
  std::cout << "Method = Brute force intersections, "
            << "Time = " << duration.count() << "ms, "
            << "# intersections: " << intersections.size() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

On my rather old machine I get:
# curves: 50
# x-monotone curves: 60
Method = compute_intersection_points(), Time = 38ms, # intersections: 271
Method = Arrangement aggregation insert(), Time = 34ms, Arr cells: 261,362,103
Method = Arrangement incremental insert(), Time = 216ms, Arr cells: 261,362,103
Method = Brute force intersections, Time = 86ms, # intersections: 161

While the second method (which is the method you used) is the less time-consuming, the running time of the first method also includes the time it takes to (implicitly) subdivide the curves into x-monotone curves (as explained above). In addition the random generation of points generates points with a large bit rate in the representation as exact rational numbers. You can try decreasing this bit rate at the account of precision. Also, as I've mentioned, my machine is rather old. A modern CPU will bring it down further.
(4) I don't know what is your final goal, but assuming that all you are interested in is the graph that you described, then I don't see how from computing the intersections you can compute the final graph. What you need is an arrangement and the code that CGAL provides or an equivalent. Notice that the module that handles geodesic arcs on a sphere uses only rational arithmetic. When it comes to implementing an alg. like the construction of an arrangement, it is crucial to remain in the realm of rational number types, and not move to, e.g., using algorithms that use algebraic number types.
(5) Your original curve is closed and the subcurves are closed (not open). If you approximate a general curve on the sphere with a chain of connected geodesic arcs, you may want to checkout the CGAL::Arr_polycurve<> traits.
(6) In order to find the direction of the vector in your picture all you need to do is compare the direction of a halfedge that lies on the boundary of a face with the direction of its associated geodesic arc. The direction of the halfedge is always such that its incident face is to its left.

For (1) that is true. I did code it with exact and then swapped it to inexact to get timing metrics. I never ran inexact with debug indeed. Thanks for your answer, I'll comment later concerning the rest of the answer once I find some time

(2) My own implementation did not depend on CGAL. It used double and therefore was inexact. I searched for all the intersections between the spherical arcs O(n^2) by ensuring that the endpoints of each spherical segment is on both sides of the plane induced by the other segment, and a few more checks to resolve the ambiguity if the segments are on opposites side of the sphere.

(2 cont.) My previous implementation did not support some degenerate cases like overlapping curves, this would be highly desirable. But in practice this happens extremely rarely.

(4) The geometric data of the intersection (i.e the xyz position) does not help with constructing the arrangement or graph. It is the location in which this intersection happens on the curve. Suppose our curve is $\Gamma  : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and there is a single self-intersection of this curve at parameter values $s$ and $t$ i.e $\Gamma(s) = \Gamma(t), \quad 0 \leq s < t < 1$. Then we know this curve creates an arrangement of 3 faces. That is the face (s,t), the second face (t, 1) U (0, s), and the outer face (t,.s) U (s,0) U (1,t)

(4. cont) I believe finding these self-intersections of the curve are required to construct the arrangement. Finding these intersections are the bottleneck to the method I outlined earlier.

(6) That's correct, thank you.

(3) I'll try posting a complete program later. Thanks for the advice.

I added a full program which shows the code I talked about. I also have a question concerning CGAL::Arr_polycurve_traits_2 which the subcurve type for sphere geodesics does not implement the trait for the ability to create X-montone. It is a bit off-topic for this question so I created another: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78945865/4048657

Again, using inexact constructions using CGAL for this purpose is irrelevant. Read the manual to understand better the "Exact Geometric Paradigm" in CGAL.
